# In MySQL, any better way to know the rank when inserting a record?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
+----+------+
| id | score|
+----+------+
| 1  |  132 |
| 2  |  210 |
| 3  |  320 |
| 4  |  212 |
| 5  |  210 |
| 6  |  188 |
+----+------+
```

And when my game is finished, I want to insert a new record with the new score:

```
INSERT INTO user_score(score) VALUE (378)
```

Right after inserting the new record, I would like to find out the record's rank, so I do something like this: (courtesy to this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40415/mysql-score-by-rank))

```
SELECT    id,score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM scores p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY  score;
```

I am thinking if there is a way to combine them? or a better way to do this? The purpose is to make it more "efficient" (less CPU/MySQL resource spent).

Comment: What do you mean "combine" them?  `insert` puts data in the database.  `select` retrieves data.  These are different operations.

Comment: Sure, thanks. I am looking for a better way then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining an `INSERT` and a `SELECT` into a single statement will not work. But rewriting your queries  as

- `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS lid` to get the ID
- `SELECT COUNT(*)+1 AS rank FROM user_score WHERE score>378` to get the rank

will speed things up quite noticable, if you have an index on `score`

Comment: does it need to sort? (ORDER BY)

Comment: No - and that's the important part performance-wise. We don't need to sort the table, to know our rank, we just need to know how many are before us, regardless of their order.

Comment: Ok, I see. You have scores>xxx to get how many before the inserted score. But what does the first SELECT do? To get the last ID and I don't see it is used in the second SELECT?

Comment: In your OQ you use `SELECT id,score, ... rank`, so I thought you need the ID of the just inserted value. If you don't need it, just leave out this query.